# Setting equal margins while keeping range of ticks as defined

Tags: python, matplotlib

The problem I have so far is that I have two plots in which, even though I specify the ticks ranges, as well as tried specifying the margins, I am still not able to get both plots to be. The problem seems to be the margins are not the same, however, when trying to fix by setting a common y margin, the result is not as the expected (second pic), it seems to ignore the tick frequency that I set. My goal is just to get both plots on the same format as I am putting them side-by-side

[image]

[image]

Here is my code:

```
plt.figure()
plt.scatter(x = x1, y = y1, marker = '.', s = 1.2, alpha = 0.75, label = 'DATA', color = 'darkorange')
plt.yticks(np.arange(0,1.2,0.2))
plt.xticks(np.arange(0,420,60))
lgnd = plt.legend(loc=1, scatterpoints=1, fontsize=10)
lgnd.legendHandles[0]._sizes = [30]
# plt.margins(y = 0.02)
plt.show()

plt.figure()
plt.scatter(x = x2, y = y2, marker = '.', s = 1.2, alpha = 0.75, label = 'DATA')
plt.xticks(np.arange(0,420,60))
plt.yticks(np.arange(0,1.2,0.2))
lgnd = plt.legend(loc=1, scatterpoints=1, fontsize=10)
lgnd.legendHandles[0]._sizes = [30]
# plt.margins(y = 0.02)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Hard to tell from your question exactly what you want... but if you are trying to make sure the y-axis has the same limits on both figures, you can just set the limits explicitly: `plt.ylim(-0.05, 1.25)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you are looking for [`plt.ylim`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xlim.html) and [`plt.xlim`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xlim.html), which allows to setup the minimum and maximum of axis. Additionally, you can include `figsize` option within [`plt.figure()`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.figure.html) to ensure that both of the generated figures are of equal sizes.  Here is an example based on your code:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

#generating test data
x1 = np.random.random((300,1))
x2 = np.random.random((300,1))
y1 = np.random.random((300,1))
y2 = np.random.random((300,1))

#setting the size of the figure
plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))
plt.scatter(x = x1, y = y1, marker = 'o', s = 3.2, alpha = 0.75, label = 'DATA', color = 'darkorange')
#plt.yticks(np.arange(0,1.2,0.2))
#plt.xticks(np.arange(0,420,60))
lgnd = plt.legend(loc=1, scatterpoints=1, fontsize=10)
lgnd.legendHandles[0]._sizes = [30]
# plt.margins(y = 0.02)

#setting minimum and maximum of the plots
plt.ylim([0,1])
plt.xlim([0,1])
plt.show()

#setting the size of the figure
plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))
plt.scatter(x = x2, y = y2, marker = 'o', s = 3.2, alpha = 0.75, label = 'DATA')
#plt.xticks(np.arange(0,420,60))
#plt.yticks(np.arange(0,1.2,0.2))

#setting minimum and maximum of the plots
plt.ylim([0,1])
plt.xlim([0,1])
lgnd = plt.legend(loc=1, scatterpoints=1, fontsize=10)
lgnd.legendHandles[0]._sizes = [30]
# plt.margins(y = 0.02)
plt.show()
```

**Output**:

[image]

[image]

**Side by Side**:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `plt.ylim(ymin, ymax)` and `plt.xlim(xmin, xmax)` to set the same plot size. Here is a code that works:

```
# Get the max value in both y axis. You could also to this for the x axis
# as well as get the minimun value. Here I'm just assuming it's zero
y1max = max(y1)
y2max = max(y2)
ymax = max(y1max, y2max)

plt.figure()
plt.scatter(x = x1, y = y1, marker = '.', s = 1.2, alpha = 0.75, label = 'DATA', color = 'darkorange')
plt.yticks(np.arange(0,1.2,0.2))
plt.xticks(np.arange(0,420,60))

# After you create the figure, set the y max and min values
plt.ylim(0, ymax)

lgnd = plt.legend(loc=1, scatterpoints=1, fontsize=10)
lgnd.legendHandles[0]._sizes = [30]
plt.show()

plt.figure()
plt.scatter(x = x2, y = y2, marker = '.', s = 1.2, alpha = 0.75, label = 'DATA')
plt.xticks(np.arange(0,420,60))
plt.yticks(np.arange(0,1.2,0.2))

# Do the same for the second plot, with the same ymax value
plt.ylim(0, ymax)

lgnd = plt.legend(loc=1, scatterpoints=1, fontsize=10)
lgnd.legendHandles[0]._sizes = [30]
plt.show()
```

Here is what i got. My data is not in the same range as yours, so the ticks don't go until the end, but the y axis scale is the same, as you can see.

[image: Both plots side by side]